# Scrapy dont save json file on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, scrapy

I have a script created in a Jupyter Notebook that scrap a url and should save the result in a json file, but it doesn't do it, even in the log it says it does. I am using Google Drive to save the files and it is correctly mounted.

I leave you the code, although I think the problem may be in FEEDS, because in the log I see that it has selected well all the lines that it has to catch.

Thank you very much for your help.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class DatosSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider_datos'
    start_urls = ['URL']
    custom_settings = {
        'FEEDS': { 'data.json': { 'format': 'json', 'overwrite': True}}
    }

        def parse(self, response):
            events = response.xpath('//*[@id="PageContent"]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr')
            for event in events:
                dato1 = event.xpath('.//td[1]/text()').get()
                dato2 = event.xpath('.//td[2]/text()').get()

            datos = {
                'Dato 1': dato1.strip() if dato1 else None,
                'Dato 2': dato2.strip() if dato2 else None,
            }

        yield datos
        
process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(DatosSpider)
process.start()
```

Comment: What's the URL?

Comment: https://geoinfo.nmt.edu/nmtso/events/home.cfml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is tested and works (although why use Scrapy for a single piece of data in that page?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class DatosSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider_datos'
    start_urls = ['https://geoinfo.nmt.edu/nmtso/events/home.cfml']
    custom_settings = {
        'FEEDS': { 'data.json': { 'format': 'json', 'encoding': 'utf-8', 'overwrite': True}}
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        events = response.xpath('//*[@id="PageContent"]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr')
        for event in events:
            dato1 = event.xpath('.//td[1]/text()').get()
            dato2 = event.xpath('.//td[2]/text()').get()

            datos = {
                'Dato 1': dato1.strip() if dato1 else None,
                'Dato 2': dato2.strip() if dato2 else None,
            }
    
            yield datos
        
process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(DatosSpider)
process.start()
```

The result is a JSON file looking like this:

```
[
{"Dato 1": "2022-11-30 15:40:32.0", "Dato 2": "32.640"}
]
```

As this looks too much like an X-Y Problem, and you in fact may be after the data in that table, why not scrape the data with a 3 line code?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html('https://geoinfo.nmt.edu/nmtso/events/home.cfml')[0]
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
    Date+Time (UTC) Latitude    Longitude (WGS84)   Depth (km)  Magnitude   RMS STD (km)    #Stations   Unnamed: 8
0   2023-11-16 13:35:53.0   36.843  -104.925    5.00    2.52    0.63    2.89    8   NaN
1   2023-11-13 20:57:06.0   35.599  -107.487    5.00    2.13    0.49    4.77    8   NaN
2   2023-11-13 16:40:57.0   34.565  -106.833    5.00    2.53    0.45    4.03    11  NaN
3   2023-11-12 11:31:58.0   32.264  -104.468    6.75    2.34    0.46    2.22    20  NaN
4   2023-11-11 14:01:21.0   32.304  -104.497    7.43    2.54    0.46    1.86    26  NaN
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
170 2022-12-04 08:08:57.0   33.990  -106.880    5.00    2.40    0.40    1.41    11  NaN
171 2022-12-01 07:50:24.0   34.010  -106.920    5.00    3.50    0.50    2.24    16  NaN
172 2022-12-01 07:41:50.0   34.000  -106.920    5.00    2.90    0.60    1.41    18  NaN
173 2022-11-30 16:34:43.0   32.640  -104.420    5.00    2.10    0.40    1.41    19  NaN
174 2022-11-30 15:40:32.0   32.640  -104.440    5.00    2.10    0.50    1.41    16  NaN
175 rows × 9 columns
```

Comment: After it works, i add all table, i have to do it with scrapy not with pandas. I execute my code on jupyter but it doesnt create the file, but i think all code is good.

Comment: Hi, dont work. log says that it is all ok but dont save in Google Drive the file: here the log: https://codefile.io/f/ub9WweCVkp

Comment: It does work. If you're using Google Colab, the file will be saved in the temporary VM notebook is running in. Just click on Files icon on the left hand side, and you will see the JSON file.

Comment: omg! i dont know that it is exists. Thank you! it works perfect!